# Replacing dictionary comprehensions and defaultdict by ordered dictionaries

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, elementtree, xml.etree

The following code takes an XML and converts it into a dictionary:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
tree = et.parse(path_to_xml)
root = tree.getroot()      
xml_dict = etree_to_dict(root)
```

where:

```
def etree_to_dict(t):
    d = {t.tag: {} if t.attrib else None}
    children = list(t)
    if children:
        dd = defaultdict(list)

        for dc in map(etree_to_dict, children):
            for k, v in dc.iteritems():
                dd[k].append(v)
        d = {t.tag: {k:v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in dd.iteritems()}}

    if t.attrib:
        d[t.tag].update(('@' + k, v) for k, v in t.attrib.iteritems())
    if t.text:
        text = t.text.strip()
        if children or t.attrib:
            if text:
              d[t.tag]['#text'] = text
        else:
            d[t.tag] = text
    return d
```

However, the function above returns an **unordered** dictionary. I would like it to instead return an **ordered** dictionary. It isn't clear to me how to replace some of the **dictionary comprehensions** and **`defaultdict`** calls for this.

An example of an input could be this one: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml

Any thoughts on how to replace

Comment: Dictionaries, by definition, are unsorted in python. You could simulated a 'sorted' dictionary via a sorted list of tuples, but you'd lose fast indexing. Python has no native equivalent of an ordered map, its dicts are implemented as hash tables.

Comment: Thanks @aruisdante I will be happy to sacrifice speed if necessary.

Comment: Well, you could wrap a dict in a class which has a ``sorted_items`` property that returns the following: ``sorted(self._dict.items(), key = lambda item : item[0])``.

Comment: @aruisdante: If insertion order is acceptable (rather than sorting by key, or something), then `collections.OrderedDict` is probably exactly what the questioner needs.

Comment: ``sorted != insertion-ordered``, so I suppose the OP will have to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly simple to replace `dict` comprehensions and `defaultdict` operations with equivalent operations on `collections.OrderedDict` instances. Note that `OrderedDict`s are a bit slower than regular dicts (and `defaultdict`s), but only by a constant factor (they still have the same big-O performance).

Rather than a `defaultdict`, create an `OrderedDict` and use `setdefault` to create default values when necessary:

```
dd = OrderedDict()

for dc in map(etree_to_dict, children):
    for k, v in dc.iteritems():
        dd.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Replace dict comprehensions with a calls to `OrderedDict` with a list or generator expression that yields `(key, value)` tuples, e.g.:

```
d = OrderedDict([(t.tag, OrderedDict((k, v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v)
                                     for k, v in dd.iteritems()))])
```

Comment: ``OrderedDicts`` are not sorted, they just maintain insertion order. If you pass them a sorted input list I suppose it would accomplish that, but you wouldn't be able to add elements without resorting.

Comment: @aruisdante: Yes, I guess I'm making an assumption that that is what the questioner actually needs. XML hierarchies are ordered, and using `OrderedDict`s will preserve that order (but not apply another one, like alphabetical by key).

Comment: Ah it looks like the OP deleted the word *sorted* from their post, so you're probably correct!

Comment: @aruisdante Sorry for the confusion. Reading your comments made me realize what I actually wanted. You were right all along. Thanks